# How to verify PayPal Subscription

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to verify subscriptions and save information to the database, in my last question I was setting up a checkout that allows dual checkout, for orders and subscriptions. I am verifying orders here:

```
<?php
    namespace Sample;

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Sample\PayPalClient;
    use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest;
    require 'paypal-client.php';
    $orderID = $_GET['orderID'];
    class GetOrder
    {
      public static function getOrder($orderId)
      {
          

          // 3. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
          $client = PayPalClient::client();
          $response = $client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId));
              
          $orderID = $response->result->id;
          $email = $response->result->payer->email_address;
          $name = $response->result->purchase_units[0]->shipping->name->full_name;
          $payerid = $response->result->payer->payer_id;
          $id = $_GET["UserID"];
          include "include/connect.php";
          //echo "#################### $orderID ###### $email ######### $name ######### $payerid";
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE User SET Active='2', OrderID='$orderID', PPemail='$email', PPname='$name', PPID='$payerid' WHERE ID = $id");
          $stmt->execute();
          if(!$stmt){
              echo "error" . mysqli_error($con);
          }else{
              header("Location:success.php?id=$id");
          }
        ?>
        <pre>
        <?php
        //echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        ?>
        </pre>
        <?php
      }
    }

    /**
     *This driver function invokes the getOrder function to retrieve
     *sample order details.
     *
     *To get the correct order ID, this sample uses createOrder to create an order
     *and then uses the newly-created order ID with GetOrder.
     */
    if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
    {
      GetOrder::getOrder($orderID, true);
    }
    ?>
```

But I also need to get subscription details to save that as well, I can't find any good tutorials on subscriptions.

Comment: Remove `echo "error" . mysqli_error($con);` as this code will never work

Answer (score 0):

Use [the current Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get), or register for [Subscriptions webhook events](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions).

There is no supported server SDK for any of these things; use [direct HTTPS integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token), or if desired adapt the Checkout SDK's source to perform these other calls.